# How to prevent model mapper from eager loading associated collections in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

How to prevent model mapper from eager loading associated collections in spring data jpa ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`fetch = FetchType.LAZY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html)?

Comment: @wilx nope - that's probably actually funny situation with `ModelMapper` when you are trying to map a model with `LAZY` field but `ModelMapper` is pushing to map it (so access) anyway, causing issues with `LazyInitializationException`

Comment: welcome so! please read [mcve] and edit post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh I had this issue last time and I must say that this is the point I start to not like `ModelMapper` :)

Basically the only way to do this is to define your own `TypeMap` with proper mappings that will ommit the collection mapping. The problem is if you have fetched `Entity` instance and sometimes you want to map it to the target class with collections and sometimes not (depends on whether collection was fetched or not).

This causes the situation when you should check whether the `Collection` field is fetched using some weird mechanisms like checking `LazyInitializationException` or the type of proxy implementation properties of the field if you are using Hibernate... madness

What I suggest is to create a few types of target Model class with or without the collection field, and for each of them [custom mappings configuration](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#skipping-properties) (if your application design allows it) or to **not using ModelMapper at all** in case of this specific entity (and just provide your own mapping mechanism)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please share an example how can I do that? The link that you have shared seems unclear... I tried adding a mapping where I set that property as null but it started throwing NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue where I had a `User` entity with a `One-to-Many` mapping to Role, i.e. one user has many roles

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;

    .............
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<UserRole> userRoleCollection;


}
```

I wanted to map this class to a DTO

```
@Data
public class UserVO implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7985084979805425972L;
    private String name;
    private String emailId;
    ......
    private List<RoleVO> roles;
}
```

Basically I needed to convert `Collection<UserRole>` to `List<RoleVO>` using ModelMapper, where `Collection<UserRole>` was lazy-loaded.

I setup a ModelMapper [Converter](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/) as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfiguration {
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        TypeMap<User, UserVO> userToUserVOTypeMap = mapper.createTypeMap(User.class, UserVO.class);
        TypeMap<Role, RoleVO> roleRoleVOTypeMap = mapper.createTypeMap(Role.class, RoleVO.class);

        Converter<Collection<UserRole>, List<RoleVO>> collectionListConverter =
                ctx -> (ctx == null) ? null : ctx.getSource().stream()
                        .map(ur -> roleRoleVOTypeMap.map(ur.getRole()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        userToUserVOTypeMap.addMappings(mpr ->
                mpr.using(collectionListConverter)
                        .map(src -> src.getUserRoleCollection(), UserVO::setRoles));

   }
}
```

The `stream()` method should trigger a FETCH for lazy-loaded data.